# Different IP Address Between Hyper-V, PowerShell, and Guest Machine

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh

## What I want to do:

Use `ssh` to connect to a virtual machine (Arch Linux) in my local machine, so as to set up a Linux version of `MySQL`.

> I considered the possibility of Windows subsystem of Linux. Due to lack of support of `systemctl` and the substitution `python2` script does not work on Arch Linux, this option is discarded.

## What did I do:

1. Install Arch Linux as well as `mysql` and `ssh` and use default network bridge.
2. Exchange `ssh` private and public key. Now comes to the problem: **find a reliable way for me to retrieve the IP address for `ssh` connection.**

## Attempt:

- `$IP=Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Where {$_.InterfaceAlias -Match "Default"} | Select -ExpandProperty "IPAddress"`
  This return something but does not work. Issue the command `ssh $IP` results `ssh: connect to host 172.19.96.1 port 22: Connection refused`
- `Get-VM -Name Arch | select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | select -Property "IPAddresses" | Format-Wide` This returns an empty collection, i.e., `{}` and requires admin right, which makes it less desirable.
- `ip --family inet --color address | perl -nle 'print $1 if /((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}).*eth0/'` This returns 172.19.109.160, and it is a Linux commands, which means it only works if we have `ssh` connection to this machine. And, it seems to be the only way that I can connect `ssh` to this virtual machine, i.e., `ssh 172.19.109.160`.

However, this IP address changes whenever the laptop restarts. There need to be a reliable way to retrieve it without rely on `ssh` connection. In addition, I ask for **why that happens?**, what causes that inconsistency?

## Environment Info

- Host machine:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro Workstation N
Version 21H2
Installation Time   ‎2021/‎5/‎28
OS Version  22000.708
Experience  Windows Experience Pack 1000.22000.708.0
```

- Guest machine:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Host: Virtual Machine Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.1
Kernel: 5.18.1-arch1-1
Uptime: 4 hours, 42 mins                            
Packages: 193 (pacman)
Shell: fish 3.4.1
Resolution: 1024x768
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: Intel i7-10510U (1) @ 3.749GHz
Memory: 377MiB / 1043MiB
```

- And more information as necessary.

Comment: Have a look at the link for difficulties using the default network switch.  There is also a link on the page on how to go about setting up NAT via PowerShell https://mytechiethoughts.com/windows/hyper-v-default-switch-easy-lan-internet-access-for-guest-vms/

Comment: Ho wdid you build your Virtual Machine ? Are you using VirtualBox or VMWare or some other methods ?

Comment: I use Hyper-V to do it. @Philippe

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! Here is the working solution:
`ssh $(Resolve-DnsName yuck.mshome.net | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "IPAddress")` `yuck` is my hostname for guest machine!